# BPMN Task continue inside other process

Tags: task, bpmn

I have 2 processes: decision and implementation. In my decision process, I have a gateway to check if it's an emergency or not. If it's an emergency then continue in the same decision process.

And here's the problem, if the task is not an emergency, then it continues to point A.

While point A will start in the middle of the implementation process. Please help me, what should I use?

[image: Process A]

[image: Process B]

Comment: It will be difficult for anyone to help you with the sparse information that you have provided. I suggest: Show us a diagramme with your current model and use it to indicate what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. Otherwise, your question might get flagged for being to generic / unlcear. Also, I find it always helps me to solve someone's modeling problem when I understand the business context. Maybe you can describe in business terms what your process is about ?

Comment: I've attached the process that I made

Answer (score -1):

You need to separate the implementation process into two subprocesses The process between the gateway and point A should be something like a Non-emergency process.